# What is the opposite of the jQuery "change()" event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm trying to use jQuery to make an input field have different CSS when it contains text. But I can't get it to change the CSS back when the text has been deleted.

Is there any jQuery or Javascript event that will do something when the text in an input field has been deleted?

Comment: You can check the input's contents in the `change` event (empty vs non-empty).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you just need to add a bit more javascript code

```
var track = function() {

    if($(this).val().length){
        $(this).removeClass('empty').addClass('full');
    } else {
        $(this).removeClass('full').addClass('empty');            
    }
}

$('input').keyup(track);​
```

Example on:

http://jsfiddle.net/demee/63nz6/

Answer (score 1):

`change()` will also fire when the text is deleted.
You just need to check the value to find out.

For more immediate reaction, you should also handle `keyup` and `input`.

Comment: I know, but I need it to do one thing when text is typed, and one when text is deleted, not the same thing for both.

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#elementID").on('change', function() {

    if (this.value=="")  {
        //no text is present
    }else{
        //element contains something
    }

});
```

`change` will only fire on certain events, like blur, consider replacing `change` with `keyup` to make it more dynamic.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$("selector").change(function() {
  if($(this).val() == "") {
   // your code
  }
})
```

Comment: Nope, that would be blur/focus!

Comment: Perhaps I didn't phrase the question right. I'm looking for an event that will only trigger when text has been deleted from an input field that formerly contained text.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#element").change(function(){
  if($(this).val() == "") {
    // do here
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you check the length on keyup, then it'll fire as the user is typing.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#text').keyup(function() {
        if($(this).val().length == 0) {
            $(this).removeClass('filled_in');
        } else {
            $(this).addClass('filled_in');
        }
    });
});​
```

You can see it in action in [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WaqnU/).